# how to record videos from my laptop webcam?

Tags: webcam, video-capture

I am not sure but I can't seem to turn on my webcam to record videos which I would broad cast somewhere later on. I have a HP G62 Laptop, and the cam turns on when I use programs like Skype and other Video Calling clients, other wise I can't turn it own, as I don't seem to know how.

Laptop: HP G62 Notebook PC, AMD Atholon II P230 Dual-Core, Windows 7: Home Premium

Can some one tell me how do I turn on my webcam and record videos? Or is there some sort of a software?

I tend to read stuff I wrote in Word, so if there is a program I need it to be in the tray dock and not to bug me, while I am moving between different documents/web pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is Windows' very own Movie Maker which can record from cam. Just press CTRL+R.
Another better option is to use the free program, Camtasia Studio, which has the option to sit in the taskbar and not bug you :)

Comment: Ye i know about camtasia studio, but i dont think it can record from webcam ^^

Comment: It's called **Cam** tasia for a reason. Any time it's used for recording the screen, they're just using it as a psuedo-webcam, basically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) for that. This allows you to record your webcam and many more things.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of webcam software available and almost all of them can record video. Personally, I used [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com), then switched to [AlterCam](http://altercam.com). Both can record video from webcam either with or without live effects. I am not sure about ManyCam, but AlterCam can be minimized to tray during recording the video, I just tried it.

One useful tip: Do not install several webcam software at the same time. If you want to try another program, uninstall the first one first. This will help you to avoid some weird program behaviour - my own experience.